# How to Write get statement in loop?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this JS code:

```
var nbr1 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr1"),
    nbr2 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr2"),
    nbr3 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr3"),
    nbr4 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr4"),
    nbr5 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr5"),
    nbr6 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr6"),
    nbr7 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr7"),
    nbr8 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr8"),
    nbr9 = document.getElementsByClassName("nbr9");

(function(){
   'use strict';
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i += 1) {
       nbr + i .innerHTML = i;
    }
})();
```

I want to write a code similar to this:

```
nbr1.innerHTML = 1;
nbr2.innerHTML = 2;
nbr3.innerHTML = 3;
nbr4.innerHTML = 4;
nbr5.innerHTML = 5;
nbr6.innerHTML = 6;
nbr7.innerHTML = 7;
nbr8.innerHTML = 8;
nbr9.innerHTML = 9;
```

So how I can write a correct code inside for to give me the same results as the code above.

CODE HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="nbr nbr1"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr2"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr3"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr4"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr5"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr6"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr7"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr8"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fact that you have to determine the variable name at runtime indicates that this approach is flawed. Besides, `nbr1.innerHTML = 1;` wouldn't work anyway because `nbr1` is a **list** of elements, not an element.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.nbr')


Array.prototype.slice.call(els).forEach(function(x, i){
  x.innerHTML = i+1
  })
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="nbr nbr1"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr2"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr3"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr4"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr5"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr6"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr7"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr8"></div>
  <div class="nbr nbr9"></div>
</div>
```

### edit

I'll try to give a basic explanation
the  method used to select the elements is [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),
then I use `Array.prototype.slice.call` to transform the node list into an array,
al last you can see the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method (all the documentation for the methods can be found in mdn, check the links, they're very helpful).

Comment: Visitors can learn more from your answer if you explain your solution and explain what the problem with the OP's code is. *"try something like this..."* is a useless statement.